# Netlify - Site has not yet been deployed

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, netlify

I built my react project (it was created using create-react-app). And when I try to upload the build folder on netlify it says "Site has not yet been deployed". On the production deploys section it says "Uploading" and it goes on forever. I tried to publish it with my github repo as well but I have the message "Site deploy in progress" and after a while "Site deploy failed". The development build with the development server works just fine. I tried hosting it locally with serve and it was working but some styles weren't applied.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried building your site locally ?

Comment: Yes I built it locally, I tried publishing it on netlify and I got the message above, I also tried hosting it locally with serve and it worked locally but some styles weren't applied for some reason.

Comment: Can you check the deploy logs ? You can check relevant details here: https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/overview/#deploy-log

Comment: The manual deploy says just "Creating deploy upload records" and netlify is still trying to publish the site, however the github deploy says that it's treating the warnings as errors, I think this is what is causing it to fail.

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding an environment variable (CI to false) but for some reason some of the styles aren't applied to my site, any idea why is this happening?